# how to store array from database in variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, return-value

I'm new to javascript and want to store (array) value from database in variable  which I can manipulate later in my code. I'm using MongoDB and this is one example of the objects that are stored.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60a2247fcfe6fbbd6ce93ee0"
    },
    "project": ["4", "1"],
    "title": "Test",
    "url": "test",
    "urlTitle": "test1",
    "urlInstance": "https://www.google.com/",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I want to store the project values in an array (x). I use this code.. I figure out that myFunction() in not returning anything that's why in the console I get "x=undefined".
what should I change in the code so the function return the value of the project? Thank you in advance.

```
function myFunction() {
  User.find({title: "Test"})
  .then(
    (myData) => {
    var rez=  myData[3].project;  
    return rez; 
  })

}

var x= new Array;
x= myFunction();
console.log ("x=" + x);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is related to database find operations being `async`hronous, meaning they do not return immediately, but need some time to do so. Take a look at [this documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) for some more info.

Have you tried `console.log`-ing `rez` before returning it? You should see that it prints the result, but it happens *after* `x=undefined` is printed. In other words, `myFunction` is not waiting for the database retrieval to finish before returning.

Concretely, you'll want to `await` the result of your database retrieval.

```js
async function myFunction() {
  // await here prevents the code from continuing before a result has been obtained
  let myData = await User.find({title: "Test"});

  let rez = myData[3].project;
  return rez;
}

async function retrieveData() {
  let x = await myFunction();
  console.log("x=" + x);
}

retrieveData();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when I try to use your code I get error "Unhandled error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'project' of undefined at myFunction"

Comment: Have you tried adding `console.log(rez)` before `return rez` in your own code? Does that work and print the correct result?

Comment: I tried that but it not work (not printing anything) and still the same error.